# HERE Maps Morocco and Western Sahara

Tags: here-api, heremaps

As you know, Morocco [disputes the territory of Western Sahara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Sahara#:%7E:text=Three%20Moroccan%20regions%20are%20within%20or%20partly%20within,Dakhla-Oued%20Ed-Dahab%20Region%20Aousserd%20Province%20Oued%20Eddahab%20Province).

We are using geo-political views (`political_view`) for Morocco, which successfully removes the border, however it doesn't remove the label "WESTERN SAHARA" from the view.

```
mapStyle.setProperty('global.political_view','ma');
```

[image: Map showing Morocco with WESTERN SAHARA label]

Is there some additional property we need to set, or is this a change needed to the political view for Morocco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using geo-political views successfully removes the border but not labels.

You can achieve it to change the program code of "transform.political_view" of styles.

1. In skeleton.yaml file (path: "sources.omv.transform.political_view") - maybe you need Map Style Editor: https://enterprise.here.com/map-style-editor/

Direct download (already reworked for you):  https://github.com/alexisad/alexisad.github.io/blob/master/vector-styles/removeSomeLabel/skeleton.yaml

2. At run time, code:

---

```
/**
 * The function add the "change" event listener to the map's style
 * and modifies colors of the map features within that listener.
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function interleave(map){
  var provider = map.getBaseLayer().getProvider();

  // get the style object for the base layer
  var style = provider.getStyle();

  var changeListener = () => {
    if (style.getState() === H.map.render.webgl.Style.State.READY) {
      style.removeEventListener('change', changeListener);
      
      const filterWestSahara = `function(data, extraData) {
            if (extraData && extraData.political_view && extraData.political_view == "ma" && data.places) {
                const pview = extraData.political_view;
                const features = data.places.features;
                let featureIdx = features.length;
                while (featureIdx--) {
                    let properties = features[featureIdx].properties;
                    if (properties['name:en'] && properties['name:en'].toUpperCase() == "WESTERN SAHARA") {
                        properties.kind = 'country:' + pview;
                    }
                }
            }
          if (extraData && extraData.political_view && data.boundaries) {
            
            const pview = extraData.political_view;
            const features = data.boundaries.features;
            let featureIdx = features.length;
            while (featureIdx--) {
              let properties = features[featureIdx].properties;
              if (properties['kind:'+pview]) {
                properties.kind = properties['kind:'+pview];
              }
            }
          }
          return data;
        }
`;
  style.setProperty("sources.omv.transform.political_view", filterWestSahara, true);
  style.setProperty('global.political_view','ma');
      

    }
  }

  style.addEventListener('change', changeListener);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

//Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

//Step 2: initialize a map
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {
  center: {lat: 52.51477270923461, lng: 13.39846691425174},
  zoom: 10,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
//map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({tilt: 45});

// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', () => map.getViewPort().resize());

//Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

// Now use the map as required...
interleave(map);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hnromqaL/1/